# Find all primes $a,b,c$ and integer $k$ satisfying the equation $a^2 + b^2 + 16 c^2 = 9k^2 +1$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

This was a problem in this year's Junior Balkan Olympiad.

So here's what I did first: If $a,b,c,k$ satisfy the conditions, then they satisfy the congruence: $$a^2 +b^2 + c^2  \equiv 1\pmod 3$$
$\implies$Two of $a,b,c$ must be equal to $3$.

Considering $a=b=3$ then $c \equiv 2\pmod9$ or $c\equiv 7\pmod9$.
The only such $c$ I found is $c=2$.

I have no idea how to proceed next and how to prove that I have found all such pairs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking $a=b=3$ we have $17 = 9k^2 - 16c^2$ or $17 = (3k-4c)(3k+4c)$. Thus $3k-4c = 1$ and $3k+4c = 17$ or $k=3$ and $c=2$ only.

Comment: you need also $a=c=3$., but good work. I'm sure you can use similar methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The other case is also similar.

Comment: Yeah. $152=9k^2-a^2$

Comment: since $152=2^3\cdot 19$ you have to separate it in $3k-a=1,2,4,8,$